# If noise is normal does that mean endogenous variable is also normal?

Tags: regression

Say I have a regression model

$Y = XB + e$

Then if $e$ is Gaussian White Noise with $~N(\mu, \sigma)$

Does that mean Y is also normal?

Just checking my understanding.

Comment: What does this have to do with the [tag:time-series] tag you’ve included?

Comment: Conditional distribution is normal, marginal distribution depends on the pattern of $X\beta$.

Comment: In particular, $X \beta$ will be normal if $X$ is multivariate normal, but this is a special case and not typical of most regressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NO**

For an easy counterexample, let your lone feature be a binary indicator variable, and let the coefficient be nonzero. Then you have a bimodal marginal distribution of $Y$ (assuming the feature has indicators for both classes).

If you want to say that the marginal distribution of $Y$ is Gaussian under a null hypothesis that all (“all“ is important) of the features have corresponding parameters equal to zero, that would be reasonable, but then the null hypothesis is just $y_i=\beta_0+\epsilon_i$, so you just shift the $\epsilon_i$ distribution up or down the real line to have a mean of $\beta_0$.